# SSL Сертификат без верификации домена

Tags: ssl

Возможно ли сгенерировать SSL сертификат без верификации домена?
В особенности меня интересует цепочка сертификатов.

Comment: Да, примеров для openssl в интернете навалом. Только такому сертификату доверять, естественно, никто не будет. А цепочка вам зачем?

Comment: Дело в том, цепочка что это как раз и есть валидация домена на сколько я понял.
http://prntscr.com/kcod39
Вот например в ISPManager требует цепочку.

Comment: По идее это поле должно быть необязательным для заполнения

Comment: Она не обязательна но если не добавить ее то - при переходе на сайт грин бара не будет а будет красный бар предупреждения.

Comment: Такое будет при любом сертификате, который сгенерируете вы сами. Обращайтесь к любому доверенному центру сертификации за получением «зелёного» сертификата

Comment: То есть, не получится самому сгенерировать сертификат с грин баром без права домена?

Comment: Нет конечно. Почитайте в интернете про принципы работы SSL/TLS/HTTPS и про центры сертификации

Comment: Ок, спасибо за консультацию!